# Flutter using basic flr and play in project

Tags: flutter

From [this link](https://www.2dimensions.com/a/SamadiPour/files/flare/liquid-loader) i downloaded basic `flr` binary file and i would like to use and animate that in flutter.

after downloading that and put in `assets` folder and define in `pubspec.yml`, that can ba show on application but, it doesn't has any animation

```
return FlareActor(
  "assets/flr/liquid_loader.flr",
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  animation: "go", //<--- how can i play or put some option here?
);
```

Comment: there is no animation named `go` in the flare project that you provided the link to.

Comment: The name of the animation is the same as the one you created in two dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the animation is the same as the one you created in two dimensions. Example: This image animation has the name idle, so you would have to put `animation: "idle"` or the name of the other animations that are just below.

[image]